# can ssh do similar things like scp under tunnel?

Tags: linux, ssh, tunnel

don't know how to precisely express my question on the title, but the story is the following. I am able to establish tunnel from my local machine to my remote client using

```
 ssh -L 1234:remote_client.DNS.gov:22 myname@remove_server.DNS.gov
```

and can transfer file in between using

```
 scp -L 1234 file myname@127.0.0.1:remote_client_directory
```

This seems to be able to save me from typing two-level security token verification for scp, but only type the login password.

I thus wonder whether I can do similar things with ssh to log into the remote client after a tunnel is set up with that machine through the remote_server. A simple test of the following does not work

```
ssh -L 1234 myname@127.0.0.1  (not working)
```

Any other ways might I try?

UPDATE:

As telcoM mentioned, I did mistaken the options in the above post. I should use -P for scp (typo) while -p for ssh (mistake), and then finally my guess works, that's really great!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
scp -L 1234 file myname@127.0.0.1:remote_client_directory
```

A normal OpenSSH `scp` does not have the `-L` option, I think you may have meant upper-case `-P` here, to make the `scp` command hit the local end of your tunnel?

```
ssh -L 1234 myname@127.0.0.1  (not working)
```

For `ssh` the port selection option is lower-case `-p`. The `-L` option is used to establish local tunneling, as you already know. `-L 1234` with no colons in the option parameter is a syntax error.

Try:

```
ssh -p 1234 myname@127.0.0.1
```